# Android studio debugger stops at random location

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I put the breakpoint at the updateChauffeurs method, it sets it at the loadLicenties method and it breaks at the loadLicenties method (see watches).

Project Clean, project rebuild, computer and android tablet reboot didn't help.

What did help was to replace the Nexus 7 (2012) tablet with a Samsung TabPro 8.4 tablet -> here the breakpoints are hitted correctly.

Any tips? Running android studio 2 beta 7 with gradle 2.10 and instant run enabled.

[image: Android studio Debugger stops at random location]

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling app from Nexus 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wukash comment was right: simply uninstalling the apk and reinstalling did the trick. I don't understand though, installing a new apk using adb didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 2 Beta is not stable yet. I think you should return latest stable Android 1.5 version in order to get rid of strange errors.