# Android studio debugger suddenly stops

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

Android studio debugger randomly exits debug mode especialy when I touch nothing for a while.

should I change some option?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222411/android-studio-debugger-stops-at-random-location